Is there a way to create an "override" entry in an Excel based inventory "database"?
Im keeping inventory for a project. I have in one sheet, "intake" and "outtake" columns. If you had a product like "apples", you would intake 5 apples on one day. If you ate 3, you would outtake the 3.
On a separate spreadsheet is a "summary". It sums up the intake and outtake and shows that I have 2 apples.
But, due to human error or forgetfulness or etc, I forget to do a proper outtake. I know apples are missing, but I never made an entry removing them from the system. So I count the number of apples by hand, and I want to enter that I have just the 2.
So essentially, I want to be able to create a new row in the "intake & outtake" sheet with a new column for "triggers", with the trigger in this case being "override". I then want my summary sheet to sum up only the values at this override and after. So effectively any history prior to the override being entered is ignored, but after that things are summed normally. If I want to override again, I just delete the override and put it farther down the excel doc and the system sums up from that later point. This would have to be independent per product. So I may want to override apples, but not bananas or kiwis. Or maybe I override them at different time periods.
I understand that the world has to be done in my summary sheet. What's making it difficult is I'm using something of a formula across a range, which is ideal for me.
=IF(LEN(B6:B10)>0,SUMIFS(Table3[Qty Received],Table3[Colloquial],B6:B10),"---")
This current formula checks if the neighboring column has a product to be checked against (the len) and puts in nothing "---" if there's no product there. It then sums up the qty received if the item in the intake & outtake table (Table3) matches the product name.
My idea, still working on it:

I am experimenting with a reverse lookup with a index/match to try and find the "latest" override entry. And will then experiment using that index/match value with an indirect to "Start" counting from that point. So if the override is on row 50 of 100, the indirect would capture the 50-100 and ignore the 1-50.

Maybe use a lambda or let function?



why not just create an "outtake" for the correction?

What if you have a single table that records and allows Additions and Subtractions for each fruit? Allow an Adjustment category in the Additions/Subtractions column. You could also have a Date column for the entries. Then use a pivot table to perform the calculation for you.

@bugdrown The pivot table is a good idea, and im playing w/ it now. Im unfamiliar with them. My only question, can the pivot table be set up to differentiate "overrides" per item? So if I filter by date, it'll filter everything after that date. What if I want to "override" one item? Instead of the entire "database" of items?

@jfwork You would have to set up some sort of flag column in your data source which you could then filter out in your pivot table.
